# Show image in php script

Tags: php, image, http-headers

I have some images without extension in their name. Now, when I want to open them some browsers can't detect data as image and show up the binary text.

What is the right script (php) which will take the address of such image, detect it's format and set right headers with image output?

Comment: why not just set the Content-Type header to image/* `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [exif_imagetype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) function to properly detect what type of image it is, then the [image_type_to_mime_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) function to get the mime type you want:

```
header("Content-type: " . image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype("image.jpg")));
```

You'll need exif support builtin though. I recommend this because it actually checks the signature of the file versus blindly assuming the mime type based on extension. However, if this isn't an option, you'll have to fallback to [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) as others have mentioned.

Comment: Since we do not know the file extension we could use PEAR ImageMagick: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-identifyimage.php

Comment: @Mathew You don't have to know the extension of the file. As I mentioned `exif_imagetype` checks the binary signature, not the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You should check fileinfo()
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php
Fileinfo detects the filetype and depending on that u can set your header.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to determine the MIME type of the file in question and then send a Content-Type header with that information in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this :

`<?php
  $filename = 'http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif';
  $file = fopen($filename, 'rb');
  $size = getimagesize($file);
  switch ($size['mime']) {
    case "IMAGETYPE_GIF":
      echo "<strong class="highlight">Image</strong> is a gif";
      break;
    case "IMAGETYPE_JPEG":
      echo "<strong class="highlight">Image</strong> is a jpeg";
      break;
    case "IMAGETYPE_PNG":
      echo "<strong class="highlight">Image</strong> is a png";
      break;
  }
?>`