# MODx Gallery not displaying images correctly

Tags: php, html, gallery, modx-revolution

I have recently set up a website using MODx Revolution. I am attempting to make a gallery, using the plugin of the same name. I would like it so that you can click a link, which displays the original image, as it was uploaded. Here is the code for my gallery page:

```
<div class="ContentHead">[[*longtitle]]</div>
<p>This page contains galleries of various images I have taken or made. Each has a description, so feel free to browse. Clicking thumbnails will reload the page, and may take some time to load a larger version of the image - but it will get there!</p>

<p>[[!Gallery? &toPlaceholder=`gallery`]] [[!GalleryItem? &imageWidth=`900` &imageHeight=`900`]] [[!GalleryAlbums? &prominentOnly=`0` &limit=`0` &rowTpl=`galAlbumRowTplCustom` &toPlaceholder=`galleries`]]</p>

<div align="center">| [[+galleries]]</div>
<hr />
<p><a name="largeImage"></a></p>
<p> </p>

<p>[[!+galitem.image:notempty=`</p><div class="image"><img class="[[+galitem.imgCls]]" src="[[+galitem.image]]" alt="[[+galitem.name]]" /><br/>[[+galitem.description]]<br />Albums: [[+galitem.albums]] <br />Tags: [[+galitem.tags]]<br/><a href="[[!+galitem.image]]">View original image</a><hr /></div> <p>`]] 

[[!+gallery:notempty=`</p><div ><h1 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Calibri;">[[+gallery.name]]</h1><h2 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Calibri;">[[+gallery.description]]</h2><p> </p><h2 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Calibri;">[[+gallery]]</h2> </div>`]]

<div style="height:600px"><!--This ensures that when a thumb is clicked, the gallery isn't pushed below the footer.--></div>
```

The code that is causing the problems is:

```
<a href="[[!+galitem.image]]">View original image</a>
```

which generates the following (example) url:

```
http://www.reflectric.com/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&w=900&h=900&zc=0&far=&q=90&src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reflectric.com%2Fassets%2Fcomponents%2Fgallery%2Ffiles%2F3%2F28.bmp
```

If you follow it (go ahead, try it!) on Internet Explorer (tested on 6 and 9), it shows the image just fine. On every other browser i've tested, however, it gives the same as you would get from loading the image in notepad++ or another text editor.

doing "Right-click Save As" on the image causes the php redirect to be saved, rather than the image, and "Right-click view image" gives the same as the link above.

Therefore, I am asking either
a) is there a way to fix this,
or b) is there a way to link to the image directly, instead of going via the php page?

Thanks for any help you can give,

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your MIME-type configuration is incorrect. The PHP-script connector.php should tell browser that the currently served URL is an image.

However, if you use Firebug (or Chrome Dev / Safari Dev etc) and check your response type, it will give you:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2011 09:11:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=29
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html      <===================== INCORRECT!
```

Content-type "text/html" is not what you want to serve, but that is what the server/php-script gives.

Check your Apache (if that's what you fancy) configuration OR, if you're using a web hosting, your .htaccess-file.

```
AddType image/jpg .jpg
```

Similar configuration exists for other webservers (nginx, lighttpd, cherokee...) as well. If it didn't work you can tweak the connector-script (haven't checked its source) to force a MIME-type. Discussed in [Show image in php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058161/show-image-in-php-script)

(I realize that is was over a month since you posted this question, but since it wasn't marked as solved I hope this will help you or someone else)

Comment: A similar issue was reported on splittingreds Gallery github-repo. However, the image was then served without using the <img>...</img>. Bug was closed a couple days afterwards. See: https://github.com/splittingred/Gallery/issues/104

Comment: This comment is the correct answer - basically it was a problem with the version of Gallery, which has been solved in the next update

Answer (score 0):

Try [[+image_absolute]] in your template chunk.

Sort of stumped why one would post this on StackOverflow instead of on the MODX forums though - there's more people monitoring that (I only got here via Twitter).

Comment: Stack Overflow does have some MODx questions - and i've asked on the MODx forums before without getting an answer, whereas I always get one here... plus I get reputation here :-P

Comment: [[+image_absolute]] doesn't work, or even resolve to a valid link (it just goes to my homepage). To clarify, I haven't installed phpthumb - just whatever came with Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Gallery 1.2.0, which has been solved in 1.2.1.

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: wolff answered it and you make yourself winner :)